# can not access standard output from a command

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I'm using this command format:

```
cmd0 > >(cmd1) 2> >(cmd2)
```

Cmd2 needs to echo data back to zenity as it processes some data, but zenity never hears the echos.  It seems the echos are lost because cmd2 is delimited by the `(..)`. An outline of my code is shown below. cases 1 and 3 work fine. Zenity never receives the echo from case 2.  I've verified that case 2 does properly echo by also sending the data to a file. I'm looking for a method to echo the data to zenity while reading.

```
function() {
while [ "$nf" -lt "$num_of_files" ]; do
    ((nf=$nf+1))
    case "$process" in
        1)
        while read -d$'\r' str1; do
            (commands ... ) 
            echo "$percent_update"
        done
        ;;
        2) #feed the standout of cmd0 to cmd1 and the standerr of cmd0 to cmd2 
        command0 > >(command1) 2> >(command 2 ....
        while read -d$'%' str1; do
            percent=$(echo "$str1" | sed 's/\x08//g' | sed 's/ //g')
            percent=$(scaler "$percent" "$nf" "$num_of_files")
            echo "$percent_update"
            echo "$percent_update" >>just to verify data exists & is good.txt
        done)
        ;;
        3)
            (more commands)
            echo percent        
        ;;
    esac
done | zenity --progress --percentage=0 --auto-close
}
```

Comment: What is the `while` reading from? You are sending both stderr and stdout to the two commands, the `while` will read the output of both. Is that what you want?

Comment: the while-do-done is really command 2 ... it is reading the standard error output from command 0 and processing it for zenity.  I confirmed that the data is correct and available by echo to a text file.  Its just that the echo command is not seen by zenity.

Comment: Hang on, so you want to send stdout of `command0` to `command1` and loop over the stderr of `command0` with a while loop? Why don't you just do `command0 2>&1 > >(command1 2>/dev/null) | while read ...` then? The `>/dev/null` is needed because without it, your while loop will get both the stderr of `command0` _and_ the stdout of `command1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are redirecting stderr *before* redirecting stdout. It should work if you switch them around. To illustrate, consider the following scripts. `foo.sh` prints to stderr and stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## foo.sh

## Print "out" to standard output
echo out
## Print "error" to standard error
echo error >&2
```

`bar.sh` reads input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## bar.sh

read input
## Print your input
echo "bar.sh read: $input"
```

And so does `baz.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## baz.sh

read input
## Print your input
echo "baz.sh read: $input"
```

Now, if I run these three as you seem to be attempting to do and pass their output to a `while` loop, it works as expected:

```
$ foo.sh 2> >(bar.sh) > >(baz.sh) | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
bar.sh read: error
baz.sh read: out
```

However, it fails if you do it the other way around:

```
$ foo.sh > >(bar.sh) 2> >(baz.sh) | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
bar.sh read: out
```

Comment: terndon,  After thinking about it for a while, your suggestion is obvious (except to me initially) ... I tried it out and it works fine ... thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify the original situation:  The first command does some file processing that outputs one flow to standard output that must be processed by another command.  The first command also outputs process status via the standard error that I was processing and sending to zenity.  By switching as Terndon suggested, I was able to get the process status data sent to zenity.  However, the question now is, is the standard output data polluted in some way by this switch?

Comment: @daniel it may well be. I'm afraid I'm not 100% clear on the details of why this works, only that it seems to. That might be worth a question of its own.

Comment: I'm having trouble to know what  question to ask now ... except to repost the question with  some additional questions ... By swapping as you suggested, it seems to work ... but I don't have an easy way to know if the data is being polluted in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very silly redirection chain you've strung together there. I don't understand what you're really trying to do there, but you have definitely misinterpreted the source of your problem. Maybe this will give you an idea:

```sh
[mikeserv@desktop top]$ > >(sed 's/^/hey there:\t/') 2> >(ls -l /dev/fd/*)
```

---

```
ls: cannot access /dev/fd/10: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /dev/fd/255: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
hey there:  lr-x------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Oct 17 06:38 /dev/fd/0 -> pipe:[10484689]
hey there:  l-wx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Oct 17 06:38 /dev/fd/1 -> pipe:[10484688]
hey there:  lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Oct 17 06:38 /dev/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/3
hey there:  l-wx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Oct 17 06:38 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[10484688]
```

Of course `echo` doesn't write out to the `while` loop's stdout - you replace it in that command with whatever pipe *`command1`* reads when you do:

```
> >(command1) 2> >(command2)
```

Redirections are processed in order - from left to right for each command. And each of those process substitutions you do all affect the *same command*.

I'm willing to bet what you're actually trying to do is a lot closer to:

```
command0 | command1 2>&1 >/dev/null | command2
```

Comment: Why "silly"? I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @terdon - it's backwards. how do you think the `sed` above manages to read and modify the output of the `ls` command?

Comment: `cmd0 2> >(cmd1) > >(cmd2)` will work as expected. Try `2> >(sed 's/^/hey there:\t/') > >(ls -l /dev/fd/*)` instead. Can't say I'm clear on exactly what is going on though. Apparently, redirecting `stderr` first fails.

Comment: @terdon - no it wont. at least, it wont unless you expect all of *`cmd2`*'s stderr to be directed into *`cmd1`*'s stdin. you just swapped streams, but you didnt solve the problem. and if *`cmd0`* writes anything to stdout *`cmd2`* gets that, too. its all interleaved.

Comment: I certainly seem to have. Have a look at the example scripts in my answer.

Comment: @terdon - again - you just swapped streams. theyre still all interleaved and backwards. write something to *`baz.sh`*'s stderr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30374/discussion-between-terdon-and-mikeserv).

Comment: Actually, I got the idea from: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet/.   It fits what was required because command 1 feeds output to command 2 thru the standard output.  Command 1 also creates status output that goes out on the standard error ... I'm still thinking about yuor suggestion but don't understand how it would work with my process flow.

Comment: @daniel come into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30374/discussion-between-terdon-and-mikeserv) created from the comments above. We can play with it some there and Mike can also have a look. He knows a hell of a lot more about the nitty gritty of how the shells work than I do.